# When creating sample android project, what would be the compile with?

Tags: android

I am creating sample project on the Android Project.

The book refers the screen shot [image]

Where as i am getting some other option and there is nothing displayed to select compile with. Please let me know how to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's a helper message, that tells you that in most cases you should select the most recent SDK installed.

Comment: Yes i read.. but there is nothing displayed on the dropdown.. How to select?

Comment: @ChandrasekaranGanapathy, Have you installed Android SDK packages?

Comment: Hi Egor, In Eclipse, Window --> Preferences the SDK path is wrong.. I have give the correct path. Now it is working..Thanks..